# 'Not found' error in upload file using jquery and handler(ashx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

**UploadHandler.ashx.cs**

```
public class UploadHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        try
        {
            string dirFullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploader/");
            string[] files;
            int numFiles;
            files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath);
            numFiles = files.Length;
            numFiles = numFiles + 1;
            string str_image = "";

            foreach (string s in context.Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[s];
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileExtension = file.ContentType;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                {
                    fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    str_image = "MyPHOTO_" + numFiles.ToString() + fileExtension;
                    string pathToSave_100 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploader/") + str_image;
                    file.SaveAs(pathToSave_100);
                }
            }
            //  database record update logic here  ()

            context.Response.Write(str_image);
        }
        catch (Exception ac)
        {

        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**JsCode**

```
/Image Upload code
function sendFile(file) {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#f_UploadImage')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'UploadHandler.ashx',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if (result != 'error') {
                var my_path = "Uploader/" + result;
                $("#myUploadedImg").attr("src", my_path);
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        }
    });
}


function callImgUploader() {
    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    $("#f_UploadImage").on('change', function() {

        var file, img;
        if ((file = this.files[0])) {
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                sendFile(file);
            };
            img.onerror = function() {
                alert("Not a valid file:" + file.type);
            };
            img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
        }
    });
}
```

Note: My Aspx page is different folder and `Image Folder and UploadHandler.ashx.cs` is route folder its wrong?

after run `ajax request` every time its give `Not-Found` error how can its fixed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your valuable feedback,

now my problem has been fixed,
problem in `UploadHandler.ashx` setting

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UploadHandler.ashx.cs" Inherits="Customer.UploadHandler" %>
```

inherits value are not matching my `UploadHandler.ashx.cs` namespace that's the problem, now its fixed.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mentioned which upload control you are using , i'm assuming it is a server side and you need to access it as follows

**Change**

```
$('#f_UploadImage')
```

**to**

```
$('#<%= f_UploadImage.ClientID %>')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said

> My Aspx page is different folder and Image Folder and UploadHandler.ashx.cs

You have to change

```
url: 'UploadHandler.ashx',
```

to

```
url: '/UploadHandler.ashx',
```

Otherwise it will try to search `UploadHandler.ashx` in the same folder as of ajax page and give 404.

Comment: Any detail in response tab?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the contentType try

contentType: 'multipart/form-data',